# HaProxy failover based on http status

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

Is it possible to have HaProxy failover when it encounters a certain http-status codes?

I have the following generic haproxy code that works fine **if the tomcat server itself stops/fails**. However I would like to fail-over when http-status codes *502 Bad Gateway* or *500 Internal Server Error* are also encountered from tomcat. The following configuration will continue to send traffic even when 500, 404 status codes are encountered in any node.

```
backend db01_replication
  mode http
  bind 192.168.0.1:80
  server app1 10.0.0.19:8080 check inter 10s rise 2 fall 2
  server app2 10.0.0.11:8080 check inter 10s rise 2 fall 2
  server app3 10.0.0.13:8080 check inter 10s rise 2 fall 2
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the following HaProxy **http-check expect** to resolve the load-balancing based on http status codes.

```
# Only accept status 200 as valid
http-check expect status 200

# Consider SQL errors as errors
http-check expect ! string SQL\ Error

# Consider all http status 5xx as errors
http-check expect ! rstatus ^5
```

In order to fail-over when a 500 error is encountered, the HaProxy configuration would look like:

```
backend App1_replication
 mode http
 bind 192.168.0.1:80
 http-check expect ! rstatus ^5
 server app1 10.0.0.19:8080 check inter 10s rise 2 fall 2
 server app2 10.0.0.11:8080 check inter 10s rise 2 fall 2
 server app3 10.0.0.13:8080 check inter 10s rise 2 fall 2
```

Source 
https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#http-check%20expect